# C# Wait Handle for Callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, callback, waithandle

I have a Problem with some of my Methods and I think, a WaitHandle is the solution.

I create a Incident through a API to a Ticketsystem.

```
private void create_Incident(string computer_idn, string swidn_choice, 
string swName_choice, string CI_Number, String windows_user)
{
    string msg_id = "" + computer_idn + "_" + swidn_choice + "";
    string username = "BISS";

    hajas211ilt3.ILTISAPI api = new hajas211ilt3.ILTISAPI();
    api.BeginInsertIncident(username, "", msg_id, "", "", "2857", 
    "BISS - Software Deployment", "", "", "NOT DETERMINED",
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "5 - BAU", "3 - BAU", "", 
    "Interface", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    delegate(IAsyncResult r) 
    { InsertIncidentCallback(api, r, username, msg_id); }, null);

}
```

This method called as a callback in the create_Incident method.

```
private void InsertIncidentCallback(server3.ILTISAPI api, IAsyncResult result,
 string username, string msg_id)
{
    api.EndInsertIncident(result, out message);
}
```

I need the message in a if, but I need the safety, that there is a message. So I have to wait for the InsertIncidentCallback and the message.

In a other Method I ask, if the message is ok:

```
private void checkIncident(string omputer_idn, string swidn_choice, 
                           string swName_choice, string CI_Number, 
string windows_user)
    {
        if (message == null)
        {
            string responseXML;
            api.REMEDY_ReadResponseXML(username, out responseXML, out msg_id);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(responseXML);
            inquiryId = (string)doc.Root.Element("inquiry_id");

            if (inquiryId == null || inquiryId == "")
            {
                information_text.Text = ".....";
            }
            else
            {
                information_remedyID.Visible = true;
                information_remedyID.Text = inquiryId;
                create_LanDesk(computer_idn, swidn_choice, 
                swName_choice, inquiryId);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            information_text.Visible = true;
            information_text.Text = "....";
        }
    }
```

How can I implement a WaitHandle to the Callback? Is the WaitHandle the right option in this case?

Comment: You didn't actually say what the problem is, only that you have a problem with some of your methods.

Comment: How can I implement a WaitHandle to the Callback? Is the WaitHandle the right option in this case?

Comment: In what case? You said there is an issue which made you think of a wait handle but what was that issue? i.e `I have a Problem with some of my Methods and I think, a WaitHandle is the solution.`

Comment: Ah sorry. The Callback is a background process and I want to show the inquiryId, that the Customer knows his Ticketnumber. Problem: I have to wait for the Callback cause when the message is not null or "", there is a problem with the ticket and the ticketsystem never create the responsexml. My thought was to wait for the callback to have the safety, that the ticket is done and I can get a responseXML.

Answer (score 1):

Using a WaitHandle on you AppPool threads, thus causing them to wait indefinitely would quickly bring your server to its knees.

Don't do it.

There are several alternatives that you can use on the web to work around this.

You could display a message to the user saying "Processing" when you send this reply.

When you receive the response store the result on that async call you can push it to the user using a framework like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/).

Alternatively you could store the result in a Session variable and use an UpdatePanel to refresh and show the status after an interval.

Comment: Why should the server goes down?

Comment: Asp.net has a limited number of threads in the AppPool(Between 25 to 100 depending on your server). Each request requires one thread. If you lock these threads, the server can't process requests. If you must make the page wait, search for how to use "Async Pages". These will allow you to use the `IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle` from your `InsertIncidentCallback` and not block the threads