# Wait handle for callback

Tags: c#, asynchronous, callback

To get data from a server asynchronously I use `getData.BeginInvoke(callback, null)`, where `getData` is the method that gets the data. The `callback` does some work & notification on the retrieved data.

In a calling method, I have read the good practice is to use a `WaitHandle` to wait for the method to be completed. My question is : Does the `WaitHandle` also waits for the callback to complete ? If not, how to do so ?

Code :

```
Func<Data> getData = () => 
{
    //... 
};

AsyncCallback callback = (IAsyncResult ar) => 
{
    //... 
};

IAsyncResult result = getData.BeginInvoke(callback, null);

result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();
```

Note1 : I have to use framework 3.5, so I can not use `async` & `await`

Note2 : I don't think this question is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135653/c-sharp-wait-handle-for-callback).

Comment: Actually, you'd want to make the async call your last one in the method (if nothing else can be done concurrently while the data is fetched) and go on with your flow in the callback. The callback will be called, when the async method returns.

Comment: This might shed some light: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/calling-synchronous-methods-asynchronously Blocking right after starting an async operation usually doesn't make much sense. You could as well call the function synchronously then.

Comment: It depends on where you set the wait handle true.  Look at msdn socket example : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, WaitOne means that the target of BeginInvoke has completed but it does not guarantee the completion of the callback. In this case you have to use `ManualResetEvent` in order to handle it manually yourself:

```
    Func<Data> getData = () =>
    {
        //...
    };
    AsyncCallback callback = (IAsyncResult ar) =>
    {
        // do your thing...
        getData.EndInvoke(ar);
        waiter.Set();
    };

    ManualResetEvent waiter;

    void DoWork()
    {
        waiter = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        IAsyncResult result = getData.BeginInvoke(callback, null);
        waiter.WaitOne();
        //Callback has finished
    }
```

Comment: Again: What's the point in using an async operation here, when you wait for it to finish right after you start it?

Comment: @Fildor It's highly likely he does something that he hasn't shown inbetween. The code he has provided is summed up and just illustrates the problem he is having, therefore I provide him with the answer he's looking for.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you @Hubbs. +1